# Django URL for 40 characters, Alphanumeric

Tags: django, django-urls

I have try following URL:

```
  url(r'^complete/(?P<id>\d+)/$', 'order_complete', name='checkout_complete'),
```

The ID I'm passing looks like this `bupkrqpltfeqpctnnagjprzegq`, which could be Max 40 characters.

How can I handle this?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume the image shows the allowed characters?

```
url(regex=r'^complete/(?P<id>[\w{}.-]{1,40})/$',
    view='order_complete',
    name='checkout_complete'),
```

Your pattern only allows digits (`\d`).

My pattern:

```
[\w{}.-] #  a character that is a word character (a-zA-Z0-9 or _), {, }, ., or - 
{1,40}   #  1 to 40 times
```